# is there any pdf tool or git project to convert pdf free annotation to text annotation?

Tags: pdf, annotations

I have lot of pdf book I use to learn and update my skills
I like to pdf annotators like the ones who let me to add free draws because the classical `highlight text` is quite tedious as you have to be precise on the character to mark etc ...
the question I have is: how can I get sthe same pdf `from free draw -> highlighted text`?
ex
given the page
[image]

**then it will create something like**

[image]

// sorry I did with paint

Thanks

Comment: Using which programming language, environment, and PDF library have you started to implement that? How far did you get? What stopped you?

Comment: I did not code anything yet  -  from high level it would expect some pdf lib and some ML to  do that - just looking for already made solutions ;)